# Can I override a Linux install? (Replace Distro)

Tags: upgrade, software-installation

I was wondering...Say, if I install Ubuntu on a secondary partition (Windows dual-boot), and wanted to try another distribution - could I just make a bootable ISO (live USB) and just select the existing Ubuntu partition for the new distribution? If so, would all my files be in place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the versatility of the distro's installer. Ubuntu is able to recognize previous Ubuntu installations on dual/multi boot computers and provides the option to replace all or keep existing Documents and programs. I'm sure that the other Ubuntu-like distros do as well. Debian Jessie might. With Mint, it depends on the version number. I doubt Arch will.

Comment: By `Lint` do you mean Linux Mint? Because then it matters the *version* of installed and to-be-installed...

Comment: Oops. Yes I did

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can do this and **yes**, most of your files (especially your home folder, but probably not most programs) will be preserved **provided** you select the **preserve my home folder** option in the installer, or backup your home folder.